# Show success message in one line with multiple link

Tags: python, html

I'm creating multiple PDF files (different language) and right now I get one success message but with just one PDF link. How do I show the success message in just one line with multiple links?

```
def _download_messages(folder_file, component, language, request):
pdf_file = folder_file + '.pdf'
print(pdf_file)
if os.path.isfile(pdf_file):
    ok = True
    downloadlink = []
    downloadlink.append("<a href='" + component.get_certificate_url(language) + "'>" + language.upper() + "</a>")
else:
    ok = False
    downloadlink_error = []
    downloadlink_error.append(language.upper() + ": <a href='" + component.get_certificate_url_tex(
        language) + "'>TEX</a> " + "<a href='" + component.get_certificate_url_log(language) + "'>LOG</a>")
if ok:
    messages.add_message(
        request,
        messages.SUCCESS,
        format_html(
            component.name + "(" + component.phpp_id + ")" + " Certificate is in: " + ", ".join(downloadlink)))
    return True
```

Succes Message : Ecocontract ULTRA(0579wi03) Zertifikat erstellt in: DE 
(Other 3 language PDF not showing, only DE is showing)

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you correctly, you have:

```
import os

### mock ###

# Django mock https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/
class messages():
    SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS'
    @staticmethod
    def add_message(r, s, t):
        print(r, s, t)

class component_():
    name = 'name'
    phpp_id = 'phpp_id'
    @staticmethod
    def get_certificate_url_log(language):
        return language
    @staticmethod
    def get_certificate_url_tex(language):
        return language
    @staticmethod
    def get_certificate_url(language):
        return language

def format_html(text):
    return f'<html>{text}</html>'

### /mock ###

def _download_messages(folder_file, component, language, request):
    pdf_file = f'{folder_file}.pdf'
    print(pdf_file)
    if os.path.isfile(pdf_file):
        downloadlink = []
        downloadlink.append(f'<a href="{component.get_certificate_url(language)}">"{language.upper()}"</a>')
        messages.add_message(
            request,
            messages.SUCCESS,
            format_html(f'{component.name} ({component.phpp_id}) Certificate is in: {", ".join(downloadlink)}')
        )
        return True
    else:
        downloadlink_error = []
        downloadlink_error.append(f'{language.upper()}: <a href="{component.get_certificate_url_tex(language)}">TEX</a>' +
                                  f'<a href="{component.get_certificate_url_log(language)}">LOG</a>"')
        return False


folder_file = 'test'
request = 'request'

_download_messages(folder_file=folder_file, component=component_, language='DE', request=request)
_download_messages(folder_file=folder_file, component=component_, language='EN', request=request)
_download_messages(folder_file=folder_file, component=component_, language='ES', request=request)
```

With outcome (in this case):

```
test.pdf
request SUCCESS <html>name (phpp_id) Certificate is in: <a href="DE">"DE"</a></html>
test.pdf
request SUCCESS <html>name (phpp_id) Certificate is in: <a href="EN">"EN"</a></html>
test.pdf
request SUCCESS <html>name (phpp_id) Certificate is in: <a href="ES">"ES"</a></html>

True
```

And what you want is to have is just a single call to `_download_messages` instead?

Then do:

```
def _download_messages(folder_file, component, request, languages=('DE', 'EN', 'ES')):
    res = []
    for language in languages:
        pdf_file = f'{folder_file}_{language}.pdf'
        print(pdf_file)
        if os.path.isfile(pdf_file):
            downloadlink = []
            downloadlink.append(f'<a href="{component.get_certificate_url(language)}">"{language.upper()}"</a>')
            messages.add_message(
                request,
                messages.SUCCESS,
                format_html(f'{component.name} ({component.phpp_id}) Certificate is in: {", ".join(downloadlink)}')
            )
            res.append(True)
        else:
            downloadlink_error = []
            downloadlink_error.append(f'{language.upper()}: <a href="{component.get_certificate_url_tex(language)}">TEX</a>' +
                                      f'<a href="{component.get_certificate_url_log(language)}">LOG</a>"')
            res.append(False)
    return res

folder_file = 'test'
request = 'request'

_download_messages(folder_file=folder_file, component=component_, request=request)
```

To get:

```
test_DE.pdf
request SUCCESS <html>name (phpp_id) Certificate is in: <a href="DE">"DE"</a></html>
test_EN.pdf
request SUCCESS <html>name (phpp_id) Certificate is in: <a href="EN">"EN"</a></html>
test_ES.pdf
request SUCCESS <html>name (phpp_id) Certificate is in: <a href="ES">"ES"</a></html>

[True, True, True]
```

Comment: I want to show success message as "Certificate is in: DE EN ES" and each of them has their PDF links

Comment: Then please provide a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example), and not just a code snippet. What are possible names for the pdf? Is the language abbreviation encoded in the name?